# How can I run the process as a different user while using CredUIPromptForCredentials

Tags: c#, winforms, credui

I did find this but can't figure out how to run the process as that user if the return code is NO ERROR

```
    public bool PromptForPassword()
    {
        // Setup the flags and variables
        StringBuilder userPassword = new StringBuilder(), userID = new StringBuilder();
        CREDUI_INFO credUI = new CREDUI_INFO();
        credUI.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(credUI);
        credUI.pszCaptionText = "Run As";
        credUI.pszMessageText = "Running Software As An Admin";
        bool save = false;
        //bool save = true;
        //CREDUI_FLAGS flags = CREDUI_FLAGS.ALWAYS_SHOW_UI | CREDUI_FLAGS.GENERIC_CREDENTIALS | CREDUI_FLAGS.DO_NOT_PERSIST | CREDUI_FLAGS.SHOW_SAVE_CHECK_BOX | CREDUI_FLAGS.PERSIST;
        CREDUI_FLAGS flags = CREDUI_FLAGS.ALWAYS_SHOW_UI | CREDUI_FLAGS.GENERIC_CREDENTIALS | CREDUI_FLAGS.SHOW_SAVE_CHECK_BOX | CREDUI_FLAGS.REQUEST_ADMINISTRATOR;

        // Prompt the user
        CredUIReturnCodes returnCode = CredUIPromptForCredentials(ref credUI, this.serverName, IntPtr.Zero, 0, userID, 100, userPassword, 100, ref save, flags);

        _user = userID.ToString();

        _securePassword = new SecureString();
        for (int i = 0; i < userPassword.Length; i++)
        {
            _securePassword.AppendChar(userPassword[i]);
        }

        return (returnCode == CredUIReturnCodes.NO_ERROR);
    }
```

How can I use this to run the process as a different user? I must use **CredUIPromptForCredentials** to ask for Windows Credentials. So I don't think I can pass those values to the following code.

```
System.Security.SecureString ssPwd = new System.Security.SecureString();
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "filename";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "args...";
proc.StartInfo.Domain = "domainname";
proc.StartInfo.UserName = "username";
string password = "user entered password";
```

Comment: So what is problem exactly? You have the password, assign it to StartInfo.Password.

Comment: don't secure passwords get stored as \0\0\0....\0?

Comment: StartInfo.Password is of type SecureString. Your code also builds SecureString. Just assign that to Password property.